# How do I make the opacity of the brush strokes not stack? I see a lot of artists do this

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When I'm coloring a drawing in PS, if I set the opacity to 50%, color, then lift my brush, then nick the same area, it stacks the opacity for a more opaque results. I want it to all be the same unless I increase the opacity, and I see this in a lot of YouTube videos. Right now coloring is nigh on impossible because all the colors stack and I have a weirdly shaded photo just from coloring.

Comment: Maybe you should give us an example of the technique. At the moment the only thing I can think off is to set opacity to 100%, but I highly doubt that it's what you want... :)

Comment: @Lollero Thought the same think, using layer opacity rather than brush opacity. But I guess it's not the best way to go since you can't really choose the actual color before you start painting

Comment: @yisela -- You should add that as an answer since painting 100% opaque and using layer opacity is really the only way in Photoshop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Scott mentions, I'm not sure you have any options in Photoshop for a brush not to 'stack'.

An alternative would be to use layer opacity instead. You set the layer to 50%, for example, and the brush to 100%. That way you can paint without any overlapping.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Masking out the different areas and colouring them on different layers might help with your problem. More layers -> more control. You can always drop opacity and/or delete overlapping colours that way.

I find that while drawing and painting, the more lazy you get and work on one layer the more problems you have later on =)